# How can I wrap lines in textarea - django

Tags: python, django, django-forms

I have been struggling with this problem about 3 months. I tried every single suggestion but none of them worked. I am sick of explain myself.
forms.py

```
class blablablaForm(forms.Form):
    blablabla= forms.CharField(label='Blabla', max_length=100))
    ...
    ...
    ...
```

html

```
<table class="table" style="border-style: solid; ">
            <form method="POST" > 
                {% csrf_token %}
                {{ form.as_table}}
                <th colspan="2"><input  style="" type = 'submit' value='Bla' /></th>
            </form>
        </table>
```

and here is 
[my output.](https://i.stack.imgur.com/EeAmM.png)
When I start to write something in the "textarea", text goes and goes and goes. I want that the text areas able to responsive so i can read what i wrote.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

forms.CharField defaults to the widget forms.TextInput. But you want the widget forms.Textarea()

So just try this one:

```
class blablablaForm(forms.Form):
    blablabla= forms.CharField(label='Blabla', max_length=100, widget=forms.Textarea))
```

See the [widgets](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/3.0/ref/forms/widgets/) Documentation for more information.